# PHP does unlink function works with a path?

Tags: php, unlink

I would like to remove a file from a folder in PHP, but I just have the path to this file, would it be ok to give the path to unlink? For example

```
unlink('path/to/file.txt');
```

If this doesn't work, the only way to get rid of those files would be to create a .php file in the path/to/ directory and include it somehow in my file an call a method there to remove the file, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the [`unlink`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) documentation:

> ```
> bool unlink ( string $filename [, resource $context ] )
> ```

and

> *filename*
>       Path to the file.

So it *only* takes a string as filename.

Make sure the file is reachable with the path from the location you execute the script. This is not a problem with absolute paths, but you might have one with relative paths.

Answer (score 22):

**Got an easy method for your question**

Use this code to remove a file from a folder

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

this can be used inside the unlink function

**worked code**

```
     unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/path/to/file.txt");
```

Answer (score 5):

unlink works fine with paths.

> Description bool unlink ( string
>   $filename [, resource $context ] )
>
> Deletes filename. Similar to the Unix
>   C unlink() function. A E_WARNING level
>   error will be generated on failure.
>
> filename
>
> ```
> Path to the file.
> ```

In case had a problem with the permissions denied error, it's sometimes caused when you try to delete a file that's in a folder higher in the hierarchy to your working directory (i.e. when trying to delete a path that starts with "../").

So to work around this problem, you can use chdir() to change the working directory to the folder where the file you want to unlink is located.

```
<?php
    $old = getcwd(); // Save the current directory
    chdir($path_to_file);
    unlink($filename);
    chdir($old); // Restore the old working directory   
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to check if the file exists, or you will get an error if it doesn't:

```
$file_with_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/path/to/file.txt";
if (file_exists($file_with_path)) {
  unlink($file_with_path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You CAN use unlink with a path.

You can also perform unlink on a directory, as long as you have emptied it first.

Here is the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: Unlinking a directory doesn't work on all filesystems, which is why there's rmdir()

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `unlink` accepts string parameter for the path.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

In other words... you have what you need to delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is it OK, it is the only way to delete a file in PHP (besides system calls).

Answer (score 0):

We can use this code

```
$path="images/all11.css";

if(unlink($path)) echo "Deleted file ";
```

Answer (score -4):

```
if (isset($_POST['remove_file'])) {
           $file_path=$_POST['fileremove'];
     // chown($file_path, 'asif');
     // echo $file_path;
    if (file_exists($file_path)) {
          unlink($file_path);
        echo "file deleted<br> the name of file is".$file_path."";

        # code...
    }
    else
        echo "file is not deleted ".$file_path."";
    # code...
}
```